# Getting a URL link from within a webpage in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Basically trying to figure out in JS (Firefox Addon) how to get a URL from within a webpage I'm currently on. I've looked online but I haven't been able to get it to work.
The specific tag is as follows:

```
<a class="down-btn sec-place" href="http://link.com" view="item for view">Viewing</a>
```

Its within div, ul and li tags. I'm not sure if I need to provide more information, or the actual tags so feel free to tell me.

Thanks everyone

--edit

Thanks everyone so far, in terms of what I've tried I've been usually using some sort of variant of

```
document.getElementsByClassName('down-btn sec-place')[0]
```

and

```
my_a_dom_node.getAttribute('href', 2);
```

Typically I get the `Reference error: Document not provided error` though.

[image: Added Picture of Area]

Comment: Depends if the classes being used on that anchor tag are unique or not

Comment: From what I can see it is unique. Cheers

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName( ) might be what you want. It would be better if you provided more information, though, like WHAT you've tried from the things you've found when you "looked online."

Comment: Maybe your document isn't loaded yet when you attempt to access the element? https://jsfiddle.net/qph9sjfr/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `document.querySelector` to find the element you are looking for

```
var link = document.querySelector('.down-btn.sec-place');
var url;

if (link) {
    url = link.href;
}
```

Just remember that if multiple elements match that selector, it will only return the first matched element. If you want to get all of them use `document.querySelectorAll` instead

The syntax for the selector string is the same as CSS selectors, so if you want to be more specific and select only links under ul and li then switch to `ul > li > a.down-btn.sec-place`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var href = $(".sec-place").attr('href');
```